# Fortify Finding: Null Dereference

Tags: java, null, dereference, fortify

I have read a bunch of the other Fortify null de-reference questions here, but none of them apply or seem to be as basic as the one our project incurred.  While scanning this block of code:

```
    private GenderCode gender;
    .
    .
    .
    if (gender != null) {
      subject.setGender(gender.getName());
    } else {
      subject.setGender(null);
    }
```

Fortify flags `subject.setGender(null)` as a possible null de-reference.  This makes absolutely no sense to me -- all we are doing is explicitly setting a value to null.  *Note that in the local class, gender is of type GenderCode and in the subject class, gender is a String.*
The original code we had:

```
subject.setGender(gender != null ? gender.getName() : null);
```

was also flagged.  What variable is possibly being de-referenced here?  We're only setting an attribute on another object to null!  Perfectly legal.  Further, the code specifically sets the value to null within an if-then-else block which *should* indicate to Fortify that, yes, we are doing this on purpose -- we are aware that we are setting gender (a String attribute on the subject object) to null.  Why does this get flagged and is there a simple, non-convoluted solution that appeases the Fortify gods?

Comment: `subject` is probably the culprit, can that be `null`?

Comment: Nope, it's not subject ... we reference subject in many locations above and below ... Fortify only flags the one statement: `subject.setGender(null)`

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, the `gender` attribute on the `subject` object is a String ... the `gender` object in the local class is an enum of type `GenderCode` ... so, when we call `subject.setGender()`, we are setting a String attribute to null.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at this, but I'm not sure we're getting anywhere.  I need some help from someone who is more familiar with Fortify and can explain why Fortify is flagging a simple statement where we set a String variable to null.